# Lua Problems With GMOD Custom Chat Script

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

So I am currently trying to create a small script for when a player, in GMOD, enters "!content" for example, they would be presented by a window that would lead them to the Steam Content for that server. For the previous example it worked so I then tried to copy over the template and just change the function name etc. I was not met with the same result as the example shown, yet nothing seem to happen and im not sure why as I have only changed the function name and string. If you can please help me that would be great. Thanks in advance.

***Steam Group Chat Script (Works)***

```
function steamgroupCommand( ply, text)  
    if string.sub( text, 1, 6 ) == "!steam" then  
    ply:PrintMessage( 3, "It Worked!" )  
    ply:SendLua([[gui.OpenURL("http://steamcommunity.com/groups/PhantomNetworksCommunity")]])  
    for k, v in pairs(player.GetAll()) do v:ChatPrint( "Player " .. ply:Nick() .. " has used !steam to view our community Steam Group!" )  
    end  
    end  
end  
hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "Chat", steamgroupCommand )
```

***Discord Chat Script (Does Not Work)***

```
function discordCommand( ply, text)  
    if string.sub( text, 1, 8 ) == "!discord" then  
    ply:PrintMessage( 3, "It Worked!" )  
    ply:SendLua([[gui.OpenURL("https://discord.gg/35rQxcE")]])  
    for k, v in pairs(player.GetAll()) do v:ChatPrint( "Player " .. ply:Nick() .. " has used !discord to view our official Discord server!" )  
    end  
    end  
end  
hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "Chat", discordCommand )
```

Comment: I forgot to add this file is positioned in \garrysmod\lua\autorun

Comment: Do you have multiple hooks? You seem to use the same identifier for both; you can have only one hook function per identifier: https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/hook/Add

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [documentation of `hook.Add`](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/hook/Add), you will see details about the needed arguments.

The second argument is important for you

> 2. [any](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:any) identifier
>
> The unique identifier, usually a string. This can be used elsewhere in the code to replace or remove the hook.
>
> The **identifier should be unique** so that you do not accidentally override some other mods hook, unless that's what you are trying to do.
>
> The identifier can be either a [string](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:string), or a [table](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:table)/object with an IsValid function defined such as an [Entity](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:Entity) or [Panel](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:Panel). [numbers](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:number) and [booleans](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Category:boolean), for example, are not allowed.
>
> If the identifier is a table/object, it will be inserted in front of the other arguments in the callback and the hook will be called as long as it's valid. However, as soon as IsValid( identifier ) returns false, the hook will be removed.

So according to this you need to change your second argument of `hook.Add`
(which in your case is `"chat"` for both of your hooks) to be unique for each hook to not override your other hooks.

Comment: @Ryke Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

This way will work, as this is what I do on my server.

```
if(CLIENT) then
    concommand.Add("steam", function()
        gui.OpenURL("http://steamcommunity.com/groups/PhantomNetworksCommunity")
    end)
end
if(SERVER) then
    hook.Add("PlayerSay", "OpenSteam", function(calling, txt, t)
        local args = string.lower(txt)
        if(args == "!steam") then
            calling:ConCommand("steam")
            return ""
        end
    end)
end
```

You can do this same thing on your discord invite.

EDIT:

I never realized you had it print to chat, so I will show you a good way to do it (or fix it):

```
if(CLIENT) then
    concommand.Add("steam", function()
        gui.OpenURL("http://steamcommunity.com/groups/PhantomNetworksCommunity")
    end)
    concommand.Add("discord", function()
        gui.OpenURL("https://discord.gg/35rQxcE")
    end)
    concommand.Add(".prt", function(calling, cmds, args, argStr)
        chat.AddText(Color(255, 255, 255), "Player", Color(98, 176, 255), args[1], Color(255, 255,255), " has used ", Color(255, 62, 62), "!steam", Color(255, 255, 255), " to view our community Steam Group!")
    end)
    concommand.Add(".disprt", function(calling, cmds, args, argStr)
        chat.AddText(Color(255, 255, 255), "Player", Color(98, 176, 255), args[1], Color(255, 255,255), " has used ", Color(255, 62, 62), "!discord", Color(255, 255, 255), " to view our official Discord server!")
    end)
end
if(SERVER) then
    hook.Add("PlayerSay", "ChatCommands", function(calling, txt, t)
        local args = string.lower(txt)
        if(args == "!steam") then
            calling:ConCommand("steam")
            for _, ply in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
                ply:ConCommand(".prt " .. calling:Nick())
            end
            return ""
        end
        if(args == "!discord") then
            calling:ConCommand("discord")
            for _, ply in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
                ply:ConCommand(".disprt " .. calling:Nick())
            end
            return ""
        end
    end)
end
```

EDIT 2:

Another possible reason for error is that both hooks have the same name, `"Chat"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're overwriting the hook. You should change the second argument to something more descriptive such as:

`hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "ChatSteamGroup", steamgroupCommand )`

and `hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "ChatDiscord", discordCommand )`